# Database goes to ReadOnly and no data is written MS Access C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, iis, oledb

I have a database with some info in it, just some basic long text and short text in Access 2000 format. Using the code I set a database to be used throughout the page.

```
 database.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path + @"\Database.mdb";
```

I have tested this code, the path is correct and it can be used to read.
In Visual Studio when I debug it everything writes correctly and fine, no database issues at all. When I publish it to a folder then run it on IIS then there's the issues. No data is written and it says the database is read only.
Querys:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Main SET Username = @new WHERE " + UID + "= '" + uid.Text + "'";
```

If anyone can help me quickly solve this problem it would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where is `path` pointing to when run on IIS? If it is not in a folder under the root of your web application it is most likely not having the right permissions

Comment: @rene Path is on my desktop in a folder, the folder and all files in it has IIS_IUSRS permission. Authentication is set to anonymous and application pool.

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to be 100% sure it isn't a permission issue.

Comment: @rene Thank you, for some reason IIS_IUSRS lost permission to modify and the folder was set as read-only. Thank you again for your help. You can post it as the answer. Thank you.